# Undefined variable, and invalid argument

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to link my array of customers to my table to output them in the table appropriately, but I'm getting these errors.  Notice: Undefined variable: customers in C:\wamp\www\son line 67
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wp on line 67

Am I going about this totally wrong, it seems like a simple task, but I'm lost.

my cu

Comment: If you do a `fopen`, it doesn't create an array out of thin air. PHP even tells you that. Take a look at php.net/fopen and check what the function does.

Comment: You should use http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file.php instead of `fopen` to get the behavior you expect.

Comment: Do your customers know you share their private data here?

Comment: @Reeno he's doing this example for a class, it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The method `readCustomers` is not correct. Try something like this:

```
class Customers{
    public function readCustomers()
    {
    $handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r") or die("Failed to create file");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line);
            //do whatever you like with the pieces
        }
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    } 
    fclose($handle);

    }
 }
```

Try also something similar with `readOrders`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to return something from your read functions within your class.

They MUST be `static` in this case.

```
class Customers{

    public static function readCustomers()
    {
        $array_of_lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('customers.txt'));
        $pieces_of_line = [];
        foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
            $pieces_of_line[] = explode(',', $line);
        } 
        return $pieces_of_line;
    }
 }
```

Do the same thing with the Orders class.

And then where you loop through `$customers` you have to do this first:

```
$customers= Customers::readCustomers();
foreach ($customers as $cust) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="chapter10-project03.php?customer="'.$cust[0].'></a></td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[1] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[2] .' ' $cust[3] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[5] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[4] .'</td>';   
            echo '<td>' .$cust[6] .'</td>';  
            echo '<td>' .$cust[7] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[8] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' .$cust[9] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>    ';    
        }
```

Comment: When I do it for Orders, do I need to declare a new array, or can I still use $pieces_of_line = [];

Comment: That `$pieces_of_line` is in a different scope. You can use the same name.

Comment: If I were you, I would try my best to understand what the code is doing, rather than copying/pasting my answer. I can elaborate further in my answer if it would help.

Comment: I'm deciphering it currently, if you'd love to go more in depth I would be greatful.

Comment: So basically, what's happening is that you're doing a class assignment and you actually don't know any PHP, right? I mean, why would you try to copy paste something you clearly don't understand otherwise?